# SSRS not sorting details as expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report with a tablix that is grouped on a supplier group.  I have a details group that contains a Sequence, Block and Product number.  I need the report to sort based on the Sequence column (first column in the details group).  My problem is that even with the sort applied at the dataset, and details group level I am getting a sort that goes 1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,3 etc.  I have 32 sequences.  I would understand if the sort went 1,10,11 etc but it is jumping over 2 and 3.  The field is defined as an integer so I can't figure it out.  When I look at this in the query in the dataset the sorting is correct.  I am at a loss.  I have tried applying the sort at every level within the report and also not applying the sort at all.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the underlying query have an order by?

Comment: Yes it does.  And the field is verified as an integer.

Comment: Can you show the query and any relevant code that gets it into the report? Ordering isn't magic, but it's obviously getting lost in translation somewhere.

Comment: Can we see the query that fires off this report?

Comment: Here is the query for the dataset:<br>//*SELECT DISTINCT 
                      RetailFormat, FeedDate, ActivityTitle, VersionID, ActivityID, VersionFormat, VersionName, PageID, BlockID, OfferID, ProductNum, PendingProductNum, Sequence
FROM         v_ViewforReport AS v_ViewforReport_1
ORDER BY ActivityTitle, ActivityID, VersionID, Sequence, PageID, BlockID, OfferID, ProductNum */

Comment: Well, your `ORDER BY` seems wrong. Why is `ActivityTitle` first, and `Sequence` fourth? If you want to order by `Sequence` first, it needs to be first in your `ORDER BY`. And if it's unique, it may as well be the *only* thing in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Have you tried modify the sorting in the tablix properties?

Comment: The order by works in the dataset when I run it outside of the tablix.  I am going to go back over that setup.  I may be that I have something grouped incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share which version of SSRS and also include an image of the report output, tablix, and row groups?

I would recommend you remove the `ORDER BY` from your SQL in the data set. In my experience, SSRS can sort this more efficiently in your tablix than SQL Server.

Also, I prefer to focus any sorting at the closest level of user visibility (I only think of sorting as useful for users). Therefore, I recommend you apply the sorting to the row group. Also, if the sequences you are using, they appear to be integers, ever convert to text, make sure you convert the field back to a number in your sort expression. I suggest you convert this to an integer even if you are *certain* that it is already an integer, at least for testing.

[image: Row Groups Sort Example]

Comment: i've fired up my BIDS machine and taken a couple of screen shots only to see you beat me to it.